# setTimeout не работает если покинуть вкладку

Tags: javascript

Нажимаю кнопку сохранить. Вызывается setTimeout с задержкой 1500.

Далее сразу покидаю вкладку, однако данные не обновляются, так как setTimeout не отработал. Хотя предполагается что он должен сохранить данные с некоторой задержкой. 
Можно ли как то гарантировать выполнение некоторых данных с задержкой даже при переключении на другую вкладку?

Comment: Кстати, судя по всему, еще и от браузера поведение зависит. У меня, допустим, все выполняется даже в фоне. Я, конечно, не данные сохраняю (хотя тоже непонятно, что из себя представляет "сохранение" у вас), но в целом у меня setTimeout и setInterval в фоне отрабатывают.

Comment: Вы закрываете вкладку или просто переключаетесь в другую?

Comment: Вкладку переключаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо `setTimeout` я предлагаю вам использовать `requestAnimationFrame`.

В примере кода ниже, когда вы запустите анимацию и переключите вкладку, а затем вернетесь обратно, вы увидите, что не смотря на смену вкладки, анимация продолжалась дальше. Таким образом, вы можете использовать `requestAnimationFrame` вместо `setTimeout` (причем использовать можно не только для анимации).

Подробнее почитайте [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) и [тут](http://html5.by/blog/what-is-requestanimationframe/).

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');

var start = 100;

function step(timestamp) {
    var progress = timestamp - start;
    a = Math.min(progress/10, 20000) + "px";
    div.style.left = a
    
    if (progress < 20000) {
      requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }
}

requestAnimationFrame(step)
```

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```